# Is there a more formal way to state that at least one condition is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am currently a student in a linear algebra class. One assigned homework problem is to prove that the product of two upper-triangular matrices is also upper-triangular. I've finished the proof, but I am not sure how to correctly word the final step. The logical argument is as follows:

$$\begin{cases} j<i\leq k \\ 1\leq n \leq k \\ \\ \text{if } n>j, \text{ then } P\\ \text{if } n<i, \text{ then } R \\ \\ \text{if }P, \text{ then } Q \\ \text{if } R, \text{ then } Q \\ \\ P \text{ or } R \\\therefore Q
\end{cases}$$

From these statements, it follows (unless I've made a mistake) that either $P$ or $Q$ (or both) must true for any $n$, so $Q$ must be true as well. I can justify this visually using a number line:

[image: Number line showing 1, j, i, k]

From the number line, one can see that for any choice of $n$ on the line, either $n>j$ or $n<i$ holds. So at least one of $P$ or $R$ is true, so $Q$ is true for any $n$. However, using a number line just feels wrong compared to the rest of the proof. Is there a more proper, rigorous way to state this last step of the proof?